# Handling ⅝ (five eights) Vulgar fraction as part of a string in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel

As part of an access application, i retrieve data from sql server. I have a string field that contains ⅝ in one of the rows, and when i attempt to insert that value into an MsAccess recordset, i get an error

*Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value.* Here is my code

```
sFieldValue = getValue() ' when i add a watch, the '⅝' is replaced by a ? e.g. "The result is ⅝" will be shown as "The result is ?" 
Rs(sFieldName) = sFieldValue ' error is thrown
```

I then attempted to hard code the value in VBA

```
sFieldValue ="⅝"
```

And the moment i type '⅝' it automatically changes to a question mark

```
sFieldValue ="?"
```

**I would like to know how i can support characters such as "⅝".** The other fractions work just fine, e.g. '½'. I do not want to do any calculations, the fractions are part of a string that comes from a SQL Server, and the problem is, i get a runtime error when i try to add a string value that contains a fraction to a recordset in access.

from [this page](http://utf8-chartable.de/), it shows that some fractions are supported in utf-8

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the field type of Rs(sFieldName) was adVarChar. So to fix the problem, i used a adVariant field type in my recordset, and it now accepts the ⅝ vulgar character.

I am creating the recordset on the fly.

Edit: adVarWChar is more appropriate, see comment below

Comment: `adVarWChar`, not `adVariant`.